# Save Foreign Characters From VB.NET to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to save foreign characters into MySQL? I've search for this and most said to change the Collation to UTF8 but I still got "??????" mark on mySQL data row.

On my form, the characters is displayed (e.g.: Arabic) but after save, "????" appear on the row. My form is require to input many foreign language; Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Russian.

How do I set my column name collation or database collation to be able to save multi foreign language?

My code when inserting:

```
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO meetingschedule.tbl_details (title,organizer,date_occur,event_start,event_end,venue,logo,user_id,dtm_added) " & _
                "VALUES(@title,@organizer,@date_occur,@event_start,@event_end,@venue,@logo,@user_id,@dtm_added);"
        myconn = New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(strc_server.strConnStr)
        stroccur = Format(udt_tempmeeting.dtOccurDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
        myconn.Open()
        With mycmd
            .CommandText = strSQL
            .Connection = myconn
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", udt_tempmeeting.strTitle)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@organizer", udt_tempmeeting.strOrganizer)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_occur", stroccur)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_start", udt_tempmeeting.dtEventStart)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_end", udt_tempmeeting.dtEventEnd)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@venue", udt_tempmeeting.strVenue)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@logo", udt_tempmeeting.arrLogo)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", strcMainUser.strUserID)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtm_added", Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
            intRec = .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
```

Example: When inserting Russian language, it goes exception when ExecuteNonQuery `"Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x84\xD0\xBA\xD1\x83...' for column 'title' at row 1"`

Comment: What's the data type of your column(s)?  I'm not sure about MySQL but, if this was SQL Server, you'd have to use `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`.

Comment: data type is `varchar`. I see some forum, discussion and tutorial about this issue for MSSQL talk about `nvarchar`. And most said, for MySQL, it support for 1 language only. I tried and still goes question marks. I don't know how to achieve this.